# How to put vowels/consonants into separate arrays and output the vowels and consonants?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm having trouble creating an array for vowels and consonants and printing all the vowels and consonants. Please help. I'm new to Java :(

````java
public class VowCon {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String x;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter a STRING: ");
  x = in .nextLine();
  vowel = (a, e, i, o, u);
  char[] vowname = x.toCharArray();
  char[] consname = x.toCharArray();
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  input = x.CharAt(i);
  if (input == vowel) {
   vowname[] = input;
   else if (input != vowel) {
    consname[] = input;
   }
  }
 }
}
```![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq3Sm.png)
````

Comment: Please help yourself and others by learning about how to [indent your code properly](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html). It is essentially impossible to read code without indentation. Your IDE can do this for you.

Comment: `vowel = a,e,i,o,u;` - what do you think this does?

Comment: Oh sorry I'm really new to arrays and I'm still learningti this

Comment: Sorry indention was a copy paste problem :(

Comment: @AndyTurner: Agreed... have been away from Java way too long. Maybe something like so would work:
Replace this line: `vowel = a,e,i,o,u;` (this shouldn't compile as is anyways) with this: `String vowel = "aeiou";` and this: `if(input==vowel){` with `if (vowel.contains(input))`. There are other minor errors in your code (that won't allow it to compile) such as `vowname[]=input` and `consname[]=input;` that you will need to fix.

Comment: @npinti: Somehow tried yet still stuck with so many problems. I'm stumped. :(

Comment: @MikMik if indention is a copy paste problem you'd have a serious problem, because parentheses don't match. Please check it and indent properly.

Comment: @Stanley F.: sorry i copied my code from Notepad++ :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.

```
 String input="This string contains your Input";

    String allVowel="a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U";
    List<String> vowelList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> constantList=new ArrayList<>();

    input.chars().mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c)).forEach(c->{
     if(allVowel.contains(c)){
       vowelList.add(c);
      }
     else if(!c.equals(" ")){
       constantList.add(c);
     }
    });

    String[] constantArray=constantList.toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] vowelArray=vowelList.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println("Constants : "+Arrays.toString(constantArray));
    System.out.println("Vowel : "+Arrays.toString(vowelArray));
```

Comment: Tried using scanner in your code still having problems :(

Comment: Use below code for using scanner it will work

**
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Please enter a STRING: ");
 String input=sc.nextLine();
**

Comment: @MikMik can you please share what error you are getting.

Comment: I put the image of the error in the code on the first post above. Please look last line...

Comment: @MikMik
You have not imported the classes, so write import statement above your class declaration mentioned in following line,
**import java.util.*;**